# Error in loadNamespace, object 'vI' not found with package plm

Tags: r, namespaces, install.packages, plm

I never had problems with installing packages before. 
When I first tried to install the `plm` package, it gave me an error saying that package `pbkrtest` was not installed. So I tried installing `pbkrtest`, but `install.packages("pbkrtest")` did not work, it gave me this error message:

> install.packages("pbkrtest")
>     Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Flo/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
>     (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       package ‘pbkrtest’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

I downloaded it manually from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/pbkrtest/ and put it into the respective directory.

Moving on, I could now install plm. Nevertheless, I am now stuck with this error and cannot use the plm package:

```
library(plm)
```

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>       object 'vI' not found
>     In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘plm’ was built under R version 3.2.3
>     Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘plm’

Here is my session info:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.3    ggplot2_2.1.0  magrittr_1.5   stargazer_5.2  foreign_0.8-65 Formula_1.2-1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3      knitr_1.12.3     MASS_7.3-43      munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.2-6
 [6] lattice_0.20-33  R6_2.1.2         plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.2.2      parallel_3.2.2  
[11] nnet_7.3-10      grid_3.2.2       nlme_3.1-125     gtable_0.2.0     DBI_0.3.1       
[16] lmtest_0.9-34    assertthat_0.1   bdsmatrix_1.3-2  sandwich_2.3-4   scales_0.4.0    
[21] zoo_1.7-12
```

Comment: I did update R, but still the same error

Answer (score 2):

If this is still an issue and you have updated to 3.3.0, try using the type="win.binary" argument.

```
install.packages("plm", dependencies=TRUE, type="win.binary")
```

Comment: what if the package is not available as win-binary, for example:

    package ‘VariantTools’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.3.0)

Comment: The current version of R is 3.3.2 (as of haloween). If you can update to this version, do so. If not, you can find an older version of the package at the MS revolution snapshot of the CRAN repositories. For example, [this one](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-06-20/) is one of the most recent for 3.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with another package (proast65.5).

The solution that worked for me was:

Go to the map with the package and open the file DESCRIPTION.
In my DESCRIPTION file there was a line starting with Imports:
I loaded all the package mentioned in that line with

```
install.packages(package-name)
```

After that, I was able to load my library in R with the command

```
library(proast65.5)
```