# "rmarkdown" incorrectly installing. Object "vI" not found

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

When installing the "rmarkdown" package to R Studio I receive the following error:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rmarkdown’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 object 'vI' not found

I have installed dependencies and as "win.binary" based on suggestions to the same issue with the "plm" package:

[Error in loadNamespace, object 'vI' not found with package plm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942473/error-in-loadnamespace-object-vi-not-found-with-package-plm)

I have also manually downloaded the package and unzipped it into the package library on my computer. None of these solutions have worked - any suggestions are welcome. I was also previously able to create markdowns in R Studio, updated to the new R studio version and no longer can.

Session Info:
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)