# How to install caret package. Tried install.packages("caret") but getting error

Tags: r, r-caret, install.packages

After `install.packages("caret")` getting below error:

```
Installing package into ‘...../R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘recipes’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
        binary source needs_compilation
rlang    0.3.4  0.4.0              TRUE
recipes  0.1.5  0.1.6             FALSE
caret   6.0-81 6.0-84              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/rlang_0.3.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1080437 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/caret_6.0-81.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 5392174 bytes (5.1 MB)
downloaded 5.1 MB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
package ‘caret’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    .........\Temp\RtmpkJG4l1\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘recipes’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/recipes_0.1.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 968331 bytes (945 KB)
downloaded 945 KB

ERROR: dependency 'rlang' is not available for package 'recipes'
* removing 'C:/Users/PBiradarP/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/recipes'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "......\R\win-library\3.4" 
...../Temp\RtmpkJG4l1/downloaded_packages/recipes_0.1.6.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘recipes’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have tried and installed "rlang" package also. Its dependent on "recepies" package so again downloaded that too...

getting this message after installing this.

```
 :Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘recepies’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

I need to load caret package to be installed.

Comment: You need to upgrade your R to latest version.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25721884/680068

Comment: upgrade R version and restart Rstudio . Try installing the package . In needs_compilation select NO . Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, try this:

Add your library to libpaths; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/change-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work). After that try installing packages; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942473/error-in-loadnamespace-object-vi-not-found-with-package-plm):

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies=TRUE, type="win.binary")
```